# Oauth Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented OAuth token based authentication for my web api.  In Oauth it used Entity framework for handling membership but I want to remove Entity framework and wish to implement my own membership.  Is it possible to use OAuth without entity framework.

Regards,
Ganesh

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET Identity, then Entity Framework is used by default to store information about the users, roles, claims, identity providers, etc.

Entity Framework is in no way related to OAuth 2.0 specification - it is just a mechanism for storing data.

If you want to remove Entity Framework and add your own custom storage provider, this link should provide you with the valuable information:

[Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

Comment: I am not using the table structures used in Asp.Net identity.  I am using my own table structures for membership.  But the microsoft OAUTH security they are using the OWIN context to validated credentials and provide token.  Is it possible to use only the OAuth security with my own membership functionality.  Is it ok with Microsoft Oauth security for my custom membership or I should go for some other way.